# Modifying method to complete removing empty string from array extra comma in there

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have tried all filters, and methods available on stackoverflow. My original output was

```
Human,,,
```

Now after using this method

```
function removingEmptyString(array)
{
    var item = "";

    for( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        if(array[i] == "" || array[i] == null)
        {
            array.splice( i, 1 );

        }
    }

    return array;
}
```

My output is

```
Human,
```

What in my code is wrong that I am still getting the last comma?

```
for (var index in output)
            {
                if (opt.options.showEmpty != true)
                {
                    var check = arrayIsEmpty(output[index]);

                    if ( check == true )
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                    else
                        {
                        var array = removingEmptyString(output[index]);

                        //console.log(index + "\t" + array);
                        //var array = arr(output[index]);

                        console.log(index+ "\t" + array);
                        //console.log(index+ "\t" + output[index]);
                        }
                }
```

Comment: show the rest of the code that produces output. Could be a `space` creating last array element

Comment: where's the test case that is giving you erroneous output?

Comment: in the console. i get human,

Comment: at console.log(index+ "\t" + array);

Comment: get `Human` from what input.... code is incomplete. Please create a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates full problem

Answer (score 3):

See your For loop doesn't work as you expected, You're looping through the array and when the condition matches, you're splicing the element on that index, but the for loop goes on incrementing, so only the next index is checked, but the splice method has reduced the array by one index so that, a "" element is now in the index that you already looped over.

What you need to do is to decrement the i value when the condition matches so that, the loop will once again iterate through the index. Hope that helps.

```
function removingEmptyString(array)
{
    var item = "";

    for( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        if(array[i] == "" || array[i] == null)
        {
            array.splice( i, 1 );
            //decrement the index
            i--;

        }
    }

    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really need to mutate the array, you should use the `filter` method.  It's simpler than `splice`ing an index, and it's more clear what you're trying to do.

Try

```
array = array.filter(function (el) {
    return typeof el === "string" && !!el && !/\s+/.test(el);
});
```